# Set globally the maximum width of a pdf picture

Tags: graphics

Some context: I use Inkscape to produce pictures in pdf format, that I import in latex using the usual function `\includegraphics{pdffile}`. Apart from keeping the picture in a vectorial format, it also sets the right size for the picture without any intervention from me.

The problem is, sometimes I am obliged to produce a pdf whose dimension go over the width of the page. That can easily be corrected manually, using

```
\includegraphics[width=\pagewidth]{pdffile}
```

, but what I would like, it some trick to tell latex to set automatically all figures to the width of the page if it goes over, or to keep the original sizes if not.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=5cm,top=5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

Some text.

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
   \includegraphics{example-image-a.pdf}
\end{center}
\caption{Some too long PDF.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've edited your question to use a PDF which is part of all standard distributions, being included precisely so that it can be used in MWEs which require such things. If you prefer, you could use `example-image-b` or `example-image-c` or one of the other exciting options included in the `mwe` package ;). Also, you need `graphicx`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This defines a new command `\includeimage[]{}`. This works just like `\includegraphics[]{}` except it limits the width to `\textwidth` if required and if no width is set manually in the options to override this. That is, you can still override the maximum if you choose.

This shows the difference between `\includegraphics{example-image-a.pdf}` and `\includeimage{example-image-a.pdf}`:

[image: old versus new]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,xparse}
\makeatletter
  \newlength\img@width
  \NewDocumentCommand\includeimage { O {} m }{%
    \settowidth\img@width{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
    \ifdim\img@width > \textwidth \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, #1]{#2}%
    \else \includegraphics[#1]{#2}5
    \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Some text.

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-a.pdf}
  \caption{Some too long PDF.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includeimage{example-image-a.pdf}
  \caption{Some too long PDF.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note:

- It is better to say `\includegraphics{example-image-a}` without the extension in most cases. The same for `\includeimage{example-image-a}`.
- Don't use the `center` environment as well as `figure` as it adds extra vertical space.
- Don't use `\begin{figure}[h]`. If you really want something to be *here*, don't use `figure` at all. (If you want a caption, use `caption` or `capt-of` which support captions outside floats.)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot indeed. Also I finally understood where is this strange vertical space on my figures coming from. But I am confused why is it better not to include the extension, or what is the problem with `\begin{figure}[h]` ?

Comment: @HcN Floats are complicated: have a read of [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020).